# How to execute execv() without full directory on OSX or LINUX?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, terminal

in C  shell programming, I learn that I can function use such as  `execv("/bin/ls",argv)` to perform the termial function `"ls"`. However, `execv()` requires  full path of the function.

I wrote my C file, in the C file I am accessing the shell, but I still use terminal to compile it and pass in arguments.

I want to simulate the termimal "ls", at the moment I can use `execv("/bin/ls",argv)` to do it,which means I have to type "/bin/ls" as arguments which will be passed to the executible.

**Now,I would rather just type "ls"  to do the task (basically saving the path typing) without the path name, how should I do it?**

On OXS,**default path is**  */usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin*,

I have try to put `execv(PATH,argv)` but it gives nothing when I type `ls`

THank you

Comment: You don't want to use `execvp()`?

Comment: You seem to be confused - what language are you programming in, C or bash?  What task are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ Chris Stratton I wrote my C file, in the C file I am accessing the shell, but I still use terminal to compile it and pass in arguments. I want to simulate the termimal "ls", at the moment I can acheive execv("/bin/ls",argv) to do it,which means I have to type "/bin/ls" in the terminmal(for a exceutabile  C program). I would rather just type "ls" in the terminal (for a exceutabile  C program, not the orignial system terminal) to do the task.

Comment: @ Michael Jaros I do, but just don;t want to type the path name, just type the function name as argument to the executible. AT the moment I type the full path name as arguments

Comment: The `man page` is quite informative:  The execlp(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions duplicate the actions of the shell in searching for an executable file *if the specified filename does not contain a slash (/)* character. The file is sought in the colon-separated list of directory pathnames specified in the *PATH environment variable*. I don't see a reason not to use `execvp()` unless you just want to torment yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Concatenates each path retuened by getenv("PATH") with the executable name.

E.g parse PATH into char* ary[], then first each path in ary, strcat(ary[i], "/") and strcat(ary[i], "executable name"). In this case, execv would search that absolute path to see if the file exists.

Btw, in terms of performance, it is recommended using stat(2) to check first before passing the file name to the more expensive exec(3) call.